# MVC databind error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, c#-3.0

I am trying to populate table ussing LINQ to SQL , I use the following portion of code

```
    <h2>Index
    <table class="grid">
   <tr>
      <th>u_name</th>
      <th>u_id</th>
      <th>u_sex</th>
      <th>u_job_tittle</th>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
   <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

   <tr>
      <td class="left"><%item.u_name ; %></td>
      <td class="left"><% item.u_id; %></td>
      <td class="left"><% item.u_sex; %></td>
      <td class="left"><% item.u_job_tittle ;%></td>
   </tr>

<% } %>

</table>
    </h2>

</asp:Content>
```

the problem is runtime error appear as following

Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

any idea to solve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to write the values to the page you need to use with `=` or `:` such that:

```
<td class="left"><%=item.u_name %></td>
```